# How to give delay in between functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is my js code ,I am reading a text file & displaying  each locations on map
My requirement is I want to give a delay b/w two position ,Right now I am displaying on all at one time

Please help me through this

```
  <script src="http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.0.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key=Fmjtd%7Cluurn90a25%2Cal%3Do5-9wt20f"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  /*An example of using the MQA.EventUtil to hook into the window load event and execute defined function
  passed in as the last parameter. You could alternatively create a plain function here and have it
  executed whenever you like (e.g. <body onload="yourfunction">).*/

  function FileHelper()
    {}
    {
        FileHelper.readStringFromFileAtPath = function(pathOfFileToReadFrom)
        {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", pathOfFileToReadFrom, false);
            request.send(null);
            var returnValue = request.responseText;

            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    var pathOfFileToRead = "LatLon.txt";

    var contentsOfFileAsString = FileHelper.readStringFromFileAtPath
    (
        pathOfFileToRead
    );
    var contentsArray=new Array();
    var contentsArray = contentsOfFileAsString.split('\n');  




    function main()
    {
        for(i=0;i<contentsArray.length;i++)
        {

            addMarker();
            setTimeout(function() {remveh1();}, 2000);  


        }

    }


    function addMarker()
    {
        console.log(contentsArray[i]);
        split_contentArray=contentsArray[i].split(',');
        vehicle_lat=split_contentArray[0];
        vehicle_lng=split_contentArray[1];


         var vehicle = new MQA.Poi({ lat: vehicle_lat, lng: vehicle_lng });
         var icon = new MQA.Icon('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gpsmapicons/blue/gpsmapicons07.png', 26, 26);          

         vehicle.setIcon(icon);
         vehicle.setKey("abc");


         map.addShape(vehicle);

        vehicle.setRolloverContent("Vehicle # KA05 9999");

     }




    function remveh1()
    {
        map.removeShape(map.removeShape(map.getByKey("abc"))); 
    };     




  MQA.EventUtil.observe(window, 'load', function() {

    /*Create an object for options*/
    var options={
      elt:document.getElementById('map'),        /*ID of element on the page where you want the map added*/
      zoom:12,                                    /*initial zoom level of map*/
      latLng:{lat: 12.922050, lng: 77.559933},   /*center of map in latitude/longitude*/
      mtype:'osm'                                /*map type (osm)*/
      };

    /*Construct an instance of MQA.TileMap with the options object*/
    window.map = new MQA.TileMap(options);

    MQA.withModule('route','routeio','largezoom','mousewheel','viewoptions',function() {



      /*Creates an MQA.RouteIO instance giving the endpoint of our new Directions Service as the
      first parameter and true that we will not use a proxy as the second (enables JSONP support to
      avoid server side proxies for route request and results communication).*/

      var io = new MQA.RouteIO(MQROUTEURL,true);

      /*Creates an MQA.RouteDelegate for defining default route appearance and behavior.*/
      delegate = new MQA.Route.RouteDelegate();

      /*The delegate is also required to customize the pois, in this sample adds rollover content*/

      var strContent = new String();
      strContent += "<b>Click <a target='_blank' href='javascript:upgradetostop()'><font color='#0021FF'>to convert to 'stop'</font></a> </b>";


        delegate.customizePoi = function(thePoi) {
        thePoi.setRolloverContent("Stop # : " + thePoi.stopNumber);
        thePoi.setInfoContentHTML(strContent);

        };  

      /*Creates an MQA.RouteController for managing the route while it is on the map. A key function of the route
      controller is to provide dragging capabilities to a route. The last parameter here is optional and is what is used
      to determine if the route should be draggable (this will be true by default if not provided).*/
    routeController= map.createRoute(delegate,io,{routeOptions:{routeType:'fastest'},ribbonOptions:{draggable:true, draggablepoi:true,ribbonDisplay:{color:"#00FF40", colorAlpha:0.35}}});


      /*Executes the route request back to our Directions Service.*/
      io.route({

        /*First parameter to the MQA.RouteIO.route function defines the route request.*/
        locations: [
           { latLng: { lat: 12.906582, lng: 77.572326 },type:'s'},{ latLng: { lat: 12.92190, lng: 77.56022 },type:'s'},{ latLng: { lat: 12.88959, lng: 77.45314 },type:'s'} 

       ], 
        mapState: routeController.delegate.virtualMapState(map)
       },

      /*The second parameter to the MQA.RouteIO.route function defines the IO settings.*/
      { timeout: 10000 },

      /*The final parameter to the MQA.RouteIO.route function is the callback function to execute
      the IO request as completed.*/
      function(results) {

        /*Takes the results of the route request and applies them to the map. The route ribbon will
        be drawn on the map along with the placement of POI's at each point.*/
        routeController.setRouteData(results.route);


        /*Change the map to display a best fit of the data.*/
        map.bestFit();


      });                                                                                                                                                     
                        map.addControl(
                        new MQA.LargeZoom(),
                        new MQA.MapCornerPlacement(MQA.MapCorner.TOP_LEFT, new MQA.Size(5,5)));   

                        map.enableMouseWheelZoom();

                        map.addControl(new MQA.ViewOptions());
      });     

  });

  </script>
```

```
<div id='map' style='width:750px; height:280px;'></div>

   <button id="getBasicSample" onclick="main();">show veh1</button>
```

Comment: you have added 2 seconds delay, did you try adding some 5 seconds delay to check?

Comment: these links can help...                                                 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval                              https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code is very long, and I can't really see which function it is you want to delay, but as a general guideline you can use `setTimeout` in Javascript to delay running some code.

In my example below, the script will output 'first' immediately, and then 'second' one second later.

```
function run_first() {
  console.log('first');
}

function run_second() {
  console.log('second');
}

run_first(); // runs function run_first straight away
setTimeout(run_second, 1000); // delays calling function run_second for 1000ms (1 second)
```

Comment: In for loop i have to give a delay..How  to give that?? Please check my for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to simulate a sleep for short periods of time:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

now, if you want to sleep for 1 second, just use:

```
sleep(1000);
```

Comment: In for loop i have to give a delay..How  to give that?? Please check my for loop

Comment: When you want to give delay put sleep(5000); represents 5 seconds delay

Comment: Sorry i am not getting it,I want a delay b/w positions Please help me !!

Comment: put sleep after this statement  map.addShape(vehicle);

        vehicle.setRolloverContent("Vehicle # KA05 9999");